# Library not found for -lreact-native-jitsi-meet ios

Tags: react-native, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm getting an error while archiving the ios build with react-native-jitsi-meet and it works fine for debug. Already tried deleting pods and reinstalling pods, adding the library to linking.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xFlG.png)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your error messages as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  You're most likely to get an answer if you include a full [mcve] with both code and errors (as text) that we can run and see the problem for ourselves.  See: [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.